# Wrap text around the image

Tags: list, javafx, label

Can a list of Label objects and picture be aligned such a way that if the label has space in the right side it should make use of the full length before wrapping to the next line.

This is because of that fact that I may not have pictures of full height of the pane always.

For shorter images I want to make use of the space at the bottom.Note that the text is a nodelist of label nodes.

[image]

Comment: I am guessing that you can achieve this by using RichTextFX, TextFlow, or WebView.